# Belgium Type D visa with code B41+University Name

Tags: belgium

I am issued a type D student visa for Beglium with the above code, what does the B 41 mean, I tried searching a lot but couldn't find anything.

Comment: **B 41** is not contained in the Annex 22 of the Visa Code Handbook (Juli 2021) *Annex 22 National entries in the "comments" section of the visa sticker* See also [BNL 2 R/FI VISA - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/171793/95267)

Answer (score 5):

A web search of "belgium type d remarks b41" (omit double quotes when searching) turned up [National statements (visa D)](https://dofi.ibz.be/en/themes/faq/long-stay/national-statements-visa-d) from the IBZ (immigration office) which says:

> B41 / Temporary authorisation to stay – Admission to studies + name of
> institution – Art. 60. §3, 3°, b) of the Act of 15/12/1980
>
> B41 – Authorisation to stay valid for 4 months
>
> At least 15 days before the expiration of their certificate of immatriculation or their visa
> D, the foreigner must go to the municipal administration and present a
> certificate prepared [in accordance with the model of the standard
> form established by the Ministerial Decree of 28 March 2022] proving
> that he they are enrolled to pursue full-time higher studies or a
> preparatory year of higher studies at the institution of higher
> education for which he received their visa.
>
> They must also submit proof that they have health insurance covering
> all risks in Belgium for the duration of their stay, if this proof was
> not submitted with the visa application.At least 15 days before

This page has a whole list of letter-number combinations which can be included in the Remarks field of the visa.